# How to handle dictionary tables in data base

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, entity-framework, orm

For example I have following domain model:

```
class Order {
    public virtual int Id {get; protected set;}
    public virtual BaseStatus Status {get; set;}
}

abstract class BaseStatus {
    public virtual int Id {get; protected set;}
    public abstract string Name {get;}
}

class Approved : BaseStatus {
    public override string Name 
    { 
          get { return "Approved"; }
    }
}
```

So now what I wan't to have is two tables, `Orders` and `Statuses`. Where Orders table will have `StatusId` column. 
The question is about API of changing order status. If I do the following:

```
order.Status = new Approved();
```

That will lead to creation of new row in statuses table. 
Currently I have created following helper:

```
class StatusesFactory {
    ISession session;                

    public StatusesFactory(ISession session){
        this.session = session;
    }

    public GetStatus<T> where T : BaseStatus, new() {
         T status = session.QueryOver<T>.SingleOrDefault();

         if(status == null){
              status = new T();
              session.SaveOrUpdate(status);
         }

         return status;
    }
}
```

And when I want to set status I'm using such code:

```
order.Status = statusesFactory.GetStatus<Approved>();
```

It seems to work fine, but to be complex with no reason. I'm using NHibernate but I think the same question may be applied to any ORM. The reason for such a thing is easy deployment on empty data base so that it is filled on first requests.

1. How do you handle dictionary tables?
2. Does my approach have obvious down sides that I can't see?
3. One problem that I see here is when I need to get all possible statuses I cant use code like:

   session.QueryOver().List();

because not all statuses may be created yet. 
So what do you think?

Comment: can't an enum suffice for Order Status?

Answer (score 1):

good question ...

i'd think that your Approved-class should use make use of the singleton pattern, since there can be only one Approved-state ...

the list of all existing vs. all possible states is a bit more difficult ... the possible states depend on what classes inherit from BaseState... i have no idea how to find those fast, since they don't have to reside in the current assembly, or even in a loaded assembly ... you should think about a static list of all subclasses singleton objects in BaseStatus ...